# Really weird error in a webview

Tags: android, webview, scroll

So I just programmed a very very simple Android application. It contains a simple webview and I want to show the user a specific registration page. However, since it is a javascript webapplication I cannot navigate directly to the subpage. Instead I need to use the method:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
```

in order to manipulate the webview. However, for some reason I do not understand I cannot scroll the page it always jumps back to the top. The problem is actually that weird that I need to show you a video I made that describes the problem (text would be to complicated). P lease have a look: [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6-iL1edx0E)

So, I think the problem becomes clear.

Additionally I found out that when I use a WebChromeClient *without* the standard webviewclient I can scroll. However, then I cannot navigate the app by applying shouldInterceptRequest which I also need.

So here is the complete code:

```
package com.example.webviewmanipulatordemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean registerFormLoaded = false;
    public WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView );
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewListener() ); // when commenting this scrolling works.
        webView.setWebChromeClient( new WebChromeClient() {} );
        webView.loadUrl( "" );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class WebViewListener extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if( url.contains("") ) {
                registerFormLoaded = true;
                webView.setWebViewClient( null );
                return null;
            }
            if( url.contains("") && !registerFormLoaded ) {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:$('#dialog').remove()");
                view.loadUrl("javascript:go('login/register')");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Hopefully you have any idea or guess what is going on in this app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I did some further logging in the method

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest( final WebView view, final String url)
```

and I noticed that the javascript (for some strange reason) continueous reloaded the page. I repaired this error by

```
if( url.contains("") && registerFormLoaded ) {
            view.stopLoading();
        }
```

in this methods. Now it work. Oh man that was really annoying. Glad that it is solved now. 
Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually see your video but I think I've had the same issue you're describing. Try setting android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on the layout containing your WebView.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. However, thanks for this advise.